# i'm getting this error but is now still working

Tags: reactjs

this the time Ago in my react but I've tried tracing the error and I've applied all the method which i can but I'm still getting it.. i'm trying to post a date to my dummy API but anything I try it returns an error ... how can i get to trace this error anyone should help me out with thius

```
import { parseISO, formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns';
import React from 'react'

export default function TimeAgo({timestamp}) {
  let timeAgo = ''
    if (timestamp) {
        const date = parseISO(timestamp)
        const timePeriod = formatDistanceToNow(date)
        timeAgo = `${timePeriod} ago`
    }

    return (
        <span title={timestamp}>
            &nbsp; <i>{timeAgo}</i>
        </span>
    )
  
}
```

this is the traceback i'm getting when i try to use console.log to use check what going on with the code

```
index.js:110 
        
       Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
    at formatDistance (index.js:110:1)
    at formatDistanceToNow (index.js:92:1)
    at TimeAgo (TimeAgo.js:8:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)

he above error occurred in the <TimeAgo> component:

    at TimeAgo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:697:5)
    at p
    at article
    at PostsExcerpt (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:488:5)
    at section
    at Post (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:107:76)
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38579:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

```
import TimeAgo from './TimeAgo'
import ReactionButton from './ReactionButton'

export default function PostsExcerpt({post}) {
 return (
   <article>
           <h2>{post.title}</h2>
             <p>{post.body.substring(0, 100)}</p>
           <p>
           <PostAuthor userId={post.userId} />
               <TimeAgo timestamp={post.date} />
           </p>
           <ReactionButton  post={post}/>

       </article>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite had a similar problem, after some toggle I came about a better syntax:

```
const timePeriod = formatDistanceToNow(Date.now(date));
```

this definitely solved the problem.

Comment: `Date.now(date)` will discard your `date` variable and return the current time (As `Date.now()` doesn't take any parameters) If you want to parse a string as a date, you should look at `Date.parse()` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse))

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?